# Composer install não roda

Tags: laravel, composer, packages

Ola eu enfrentando um problema aqui no qual não estou conseguindo rodar o composer install e estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

> Erro ao executar composer install

```
 Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for hashids/hashids 4.0.0 -> satisfiable by hashids/hashids[4.0.0].
    - hashids/hashids 4.0.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for laravel/framework v7.4.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.4.0].
    - laravel/framework v7.4.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
  Problem 3
    - Installation request for lcobucci/jwt 3.3.1 -> satisfiable by lcobucci/jwt[3.3.1].
    - lcobucci/jwt 3.3.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
  Problem 4
    - Installation request for league/commonmark 1.3.2 -> satisfiable by league/commonmark[1.3.2].
    - league/commonmark 1.3.2 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
  Problem 5
    - Installation request for facade/ignition 2.0.2 -> satisfiable by facade/ignition[2.0.2].
    - facade/ignition 2.0.2 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
  Problem 6
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit 8.5.3 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[8.5.3].
    - phpunit/phpunit 8.5.3 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
  Problem 7
    - Installation request for scrivo/highlight.php v9.18.1.1 -> satisfiable by scrivo/highlight.php[v9.18.1.1].
    - scrivo/highlight.php v9.18.1.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
  Problem 8
    - laravel/framework v7.4.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - facade/flare-client-php 1.3.2 requires illuminate/pipeline ^5.5|^6.0|^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.4.0].
    - Installation request for facade/flare-client-php 1.3.2 -> satisfiable by facade/flare-client-php[1.3.2].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

> Composer json ultilizado

```
    {
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
        "laravel/passport": "^8.4",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "laravel/ui": "^2.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^6.1",
        "mtvs/eloquent-hashids": "^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Aguem sabe me informar aonde estou errando? E como eu posso estar sanando este problema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Está faltando ou está desabilitada a extensão **mbstring** do php no seu ambiente ou máquina necessário para o composer.

Caso seja linux derivado do Ubuntu/Debian, tente:

```
$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
```

Depois rode `composer install` novamente.

Caso seja no windows com stacks prontas, como Wamp ou Xampp, terá que buscar a solução de acordo.

Comment: Valeu mesmo, era isso,muito obrigada.

Comment: De nada, amigo. Só um sugestão. Não sei se é possível, mas se conseguir mudar no título da pergunta: "isntall" para "install", acredito que fica mais fácil de achar para ajudar outros com o mesmo problema. Abraço.

Answer (score 1):

Os packages que você está usando necessitam da extensão: `mbstring`.
Conforme informado; `the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.`

Instale a extensão e tente novamente.